# Array of JQuery-elements in TypeScript has wrong type when iterating

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, foreach

In my `TypeScript` class I have an array of `JQuery` elements which gets filled by calling

```
this.$elements = $sourceElement.find(`[data-filter-element]`).toArray();
```

whereas `$elements : JQuery[];` is defined this way.

The problem is when I try to iterate over those elements:

```
this.$elements.forEach((current) => {
    var $current = $(current); // <-- why do I have to do this?
    // ...
});
```

Why is `current` not of the correct type (`JQuery`) here?

I also tried using

```
for(let current of this.$elements){
    // same issue here
}
```

as well as

```
$.each(this.$elements, (idx, current) => {
    // same issue here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects represent lists of DOM elements, [by definition](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

They do not represent lists of *even more* jQuery objects.

That's all there is to say to this, really.